# Adding backend instance to Android Google Endpoints project

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I successfully built a small Google Endpoints App with Android Studio and its predefined, gradle-based template for using it with Android.
Now, the requirements are getting more complicated and I also need a "backend instance" for some background tasks.

However, I can't figure out how to change the project structure or add the "backend instance" as another module which integrates into the current Gradle setup.

Right now the structure is like following:

- app (Android)
- backend (app engine)

  - src/main/java
  - src/main/webapp

    - WEB-INF

      - appengine-web.xml
      - web.xml

I am using following app engine gradle plugin: com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17

Any ideas how to add a "backend instance" to this setup?

Comment: Could you please point to the docs that tell you that you need a "backend instance"?

Comment: ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread throws following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This feature is only available to backend instances.
If I use ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest, then the thread gets killed when the request on the request thread is done. The API says: "These threads will be interrupted at the end of the current request and must complete within the request deadline."

Comment: I think you're talking about backends which have been deprecated in favor of modules. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends).

What are you trying to do that requires you to run a background thread?

Comment: When users submitted certain objects via the android app the server will start a background thread where gcm registration ids will be fetched from datastore and messages will be send to certain clients. I also have to handle expired and unused ids I'll get back from google which I have to delete then from the datastore. I don't think its a good idea to do that on the request thread. How would you guys tackle that problem?

Comment: One options is task queues: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/